# Exclude subfolders with glob

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory, glob

I am trying to use glob.iglob to search for xml files in all subfolders of a specific folder. The problem is that there are some folders linked in and I get in some kind of neverending subfolderpath. For example:

```
First Level\
 Second Level A\
  Third Level: Link to Second Level B\
  Third Level: subfolder with xml files\
 Second Level B\
  Third Level: Link to Second Level A\
  Third Level: subfolder with xml files\
```

So I need to exclude some subfolder by their name. Is there a way to do so?
I already tried to pass a list like:

```
glob.iglob([r'/**/*.xml', r'!/Link to Second Level B/'])
```

But this did not work for me.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to start by pointing out that this kind of (recurring) *symlink*ing is a sign of bad design. Any fix would be fixing the effect of the problem not the cause ("sweeping the dirt under the carpet").

Unfortunately, (the recurring) *glob* doesn't allow filtering, nor does it provide access to elements while enumerating them. So, you need another way, by enumerating the *dir* elements yourself (using one of many existing ways - you could take a look at [[SO]: How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions/44661513#44661513)) and filter out the unwanted ones.

Here's the test *dir* structure. Note that here, the 2 recurring *symlink*s are actually normal *dir*s, otherwise they would have messed up the command (which doesn't handle this case either). I replaced them by *symlink*s afterwards:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057591233]> tree /a /f .
> Folder PATH listing for volume Work
> Volume serial number is 3655-6FED
> E:\WORK\DEV\STACKOVERFLOW\Q057591233
> |   code00.py
> |
> +---external_dir
> |       file00.xml
> |
> \---search_dir
>     |   file00.xml
>     |   file01.xml
>     |
>     +---dir00
>     |   +---dir00
>     |   |   |   file00.xml
>     |   |   |
>     |   |   \---dir00
>     |   |           file00.xml
>     |   |
>     |   \---dir01_symlink_to_parent_sibbling_dir01
>     \---dir01
>         +---dir00_symlink_to_parent_sibbling_dir00
>         +---dir01
>         |       file00.xml
>         |
>         \---dir02_symlink_to_external_dir
>                 file00_ext.xml
> ```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import re
import pprint


def _get_files_os_scandir_no_symlikns(dir_name, match_func, level=0):
    for item in os.scandir(dir_name):
        if item.is_symlink():
            continue
        if item.is_dir():
            yield from _get_files_os_scandir_no_symlikns(item.path, match_func, level=level + 1)
        elif match_func(item.path):
            yield item.path


def _get_files_os_scandir(dir_name, match_func, visited_inodes, level=0):
    for item in os.scandir(dir_name):
        if item.inode() in visited_inodes:
            continue
        visited_inodes.append(item.inode())
        item_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(*os.path.split(item.path)[:-1], os.readlink(item.path))) if item.is_symlink() else item.path
        if item.is_dir():
            yield from _get_files_os_scandir(item_path, match_func, visited_inodes, level=level + 1)
        elif match_func(item_path):
            yield item_path


def get_files(path, ext, exclude_symlinks=True):
    if exclude_symlinks and os.path.islink(path):
        return
    pattern = re.compile(".*\.{0:s}$".format(ext))
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if exclude_symlinks:
            yield from _get_files_os_scandir_no_symlikns(path, pattern.match)
        else:
            yield from _get_files_os_scandir(path, pattern.match, list())
    elif os.path.isfile(path) and pattern.match(path):
        yield path


def main():
    search_dir = "search_dir"
    extension = "xml"
    for exclude_symlinks in [True, False]:
        print("\nExclude symlinks: {0:}".format(exclude_symlinks))
        files = list(get_files(search_dir, extension, exclude_symlinks=exclude_symlinks))
        pprint.pprint(files)
        print("Total items: {0:d}".format(len(files)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057591233]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
>
> Exclude symlinks: True
> ['search_dir\\dir00\\dir00\\dir00\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\dir00\\dir00\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\dir01\\dir01\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\file01.xml']
> Total items: 5
>
> Exclude symlinks: False
> ['search_dir\\dir00\\dir00\\dir00\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\dir00\\dir00\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\dir01\\dir01\\file00.xml',
>  'external_dir\\file00_ext.xml',
>  'search_dir\\file00.xml',
>  'search_dir\\file01.xml']
> Total items: 6
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- The recursive implementation relies on [[Python 3.Docs]: os.**scandir**(*path='.'*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) (and other file / *dir* functions)
- In terms of file name matching, there's no wildcards support, so the closest (?) thing (*regexp*) is used
- The 2 functions traversing the *dir*:

  - *_get_files_os_scandir_no_symlikns* - ignores all *symlink*s
  - *_get_files_os_scandir* - includes *symlinks*. Also does some processing to avoid infinite recursion and for *symlink* resolution
- The 2 functions could have been unified (with an extra argument (*exclude_symlinks*)), but I got a feeling that the one ignoring them performs much faster this way
- As seen, none enters infinite recursion (for the former it's obvious), but the former also omits the file external to the search *dir*
- *get_files_os_scandir* - a wrapper that calls either one of the 2, after it does some initialization work (to avoid doing it by each recurring call)
- I only ran the code on *Win*, but I ran parts of it on *Nix* as well, so I'm not expecting any surprises there

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change this symlinking. Meanwhile I changed my program to search only in subfolders without symlinking but now I will try your solution. So thanks a lot for your work!

Comment: Noone said to change *symlink*. This is why I posted the code :). Searching each dir is OK too, but if there are many subdirs, and the *symlink*s are somewhere lower in the tree, it won't work.